# Laravel inner join to return specific result only

Tags: php, sql, laravel, model-view-controller

I have simple select query using inner join of two tables. The problem is when i return the title only i got this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

But when i return all of the json it works perfectly. I want to use the title to query. How can i solve this issue?

```
    $products = DB::table('products');
    $messages = $products
        ->join('bookings', 'products.id', '=', 'bookings.ProductID')
        ->where('EmailAddress', '=', ''. $userEmail . '')
        ->orderBy("bookings.DateCreated", "desc")
        ->get();
    return $messages->Title;
```

Comment: $messages is an array, not an object. Iterate over the array.

Comment: Okay thanks. Ill try that. However i want to use the title to query?

Answer (score 0):

Your code or query returns multiple Result, so you need to loop or iterate it:-

```
$products = DB::table('products');
$messages = $products
    ->join('bookings', 'products.id', '=', 'bookings.ProductID')
    ->where('EmailAddress', '=', ''. $userEmail . '')
    ->orderBy("bookings.DateCreated", "desc")
    ->get();
return $messages->Title;
```

According to your code it seems you need only first row of result, so change your code as (replace ->get() with ->first()) :-

```
$products = DB::table('products');
$messages = $products
    ->join('bookings', 'products.id', '=', 'bookings.ProductID')
    ->where('EmailAddress', '=', ''. $userEmail . '')
    ->orderBy("bookings.DateCreated", "desc")
    ->first();
return $messages->Title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try with Eloquent Eager Loading. So you will get the Object return.

```
$messages = Products::with(['bookings' => function ($query) use ($userEmail) {
    $query->where('EmailAddress', '=', ''. $userEmail . '');
    $query->orderBy("bookings.DateCreated", "desc");
}])->get();

Try similar like this. Hope you will get the collection.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers. But i found my solution. I used to inner join and put an aliases.

```
    $products = DB::table('products');
    $messages = $products
        ->join('bookings AS b1', 'products.id', '=', 'b1.ProductID')
        ->join('booking_notifications as b2', 'b1.Code', '=', 'b2.Code')
        ->where('Products.EmailAddress', '=', ''. $userEmail . '')
        ->orderBy("b1.DateCreated", "desc")       
        ->get(); 

    return view('messages.index')->with('messages', $messages);;
```

Comment: This shouldn't work and should throw the same error.